# R- html_nodes doesnt find selector

Tags: css, r

I wanted to scrap some data with "rvest" package from url http://www.finanzen.ch/kurse/historisch/ABB/SWL/1.1.2001_27.10.2015

I wanted to get the table with the following selector (copied via inspect option from chrome):

```
#historic-price-list > div > div.content > table
```

But html_nodes doesn't work:

```
> url="http://www.finanzen.ch/kurse/historisch/ABB/SWL/1.1.2001_27.10.2015"
> css_selector="#historic-price-list > div > div.content > table"
> html(url) %>% html_nodes(css_selector)
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

What I can find is:

```
> css_selector="#historic-price-list"
> html(url) %>% html_nodes(css_selector)
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <div id="historic-price-list"/>
```

But it doesn't goes any further.
Maybe someone got an idea why?

Comment: Did you try it without the direct descendent selectors? I.e. `#historic-price-list div.content_box div.content table`. I have never used R or rvest, so I'm just taking a shot in the dark, thinking they may not have implemented that type of behavior.

Comment: It's generated by javascript, specifically calls to some back-end resource buy angular (a js framework). You'll need to parse the XHR requests themselves or use selenium.

Comment: And, you will definitely need to use selenium. It hashes some values per-request to avoid this scraping and, upon inspection of their Terms of Service what you are attempting to do violates _"In particular, an automated query of the content provided by finanzen.net without express written permission in any form is not allowed."_ unless you can show us you've got said written permission.